# Postgres, Typeorm save in field of array of indexes instead of relations

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, typeorm

I am kinda new to typeorm and postgres, and I have mostly worked with noSQL like mongodb.

I was wondering, instead of using relations like one to many or one to one, can we store a field Id or Ids?

Is there a disadvantage to this?
and if I can, how to insert and array of ids to a field, cause it does not add it?

PS. I am using typeorm in JS and not TS and I am half way crying with so little documentation on JS docs with typeorm specially in relations!!!

Comment: If that is what you want to do stick with mongodb.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you, I would but the company wants it in postgres. I was wondering what are the advantages of doing it with relations. It seems we have to do everything as we did earlier

Comment: If you are in Postgres you will be using relations whatever you do. What you end up with is burying an array in a relation and then doing double work to get it out. If you want to use a relational database then use it as such, if not stick with the NoSQL  solution.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver do you know what are the advantages of using relational db in oppose of using non-relational one? Like why are they still in use? Can't we get the same speed and performance by adding indexes to mongodb schema?

Comment: This is really outside the scope of a SO question. Really the only way you are going to know is set up a realistic test set and apply in both MongoDB and Postgres. There are two many usage variables involved.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you, I did but can't seem to see any real advantage for postgres and sql dbs in general. I guess I'm going to get it with more experience!

Comment: Given that there are terabyte and petabyte databases out there I would say someone has found a use for them.  What you need to do is define, at least to yourself, what you want to do with the data. This includes at a minimum where is id coming from, how is being entered, what are the relationships between the data sets and how is it going to be used by end users?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 
you mean nosql dbs will fall significantly behind with huge amount of data in oppose to sql dbs?

Comment: No that is not what I said. I pointed out that SQL databases have uses. What you choose to use depends on your data and what you want to do with it. This is a topic that is to broad for this forum though, so I will not pursing this conversation further.